# How to use regex with pandas series.find function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find the location of a regex in a dataframe series and assign it to another series. I can do this for string with

```
df['text'].str.lower().str.find('hello')
```

This function gives the index of the match. like

```
text
World Hello
Hello WOrld
WOW
```

using this

```
df['match_ind'] = df['text'].str.lower().str.find('hello')
```

it gives

```
text            match_ind
World Hello     6
Hello WOrld     0
WOW             -1
```

but instead of `hello`, I want to use a regex say `'hello|world'`. Currently, it's giving me -1

```
df['text'].str.lower().str.find('hello|world')
```

I am using python3

Does pandas find supports regex or is there some pandas way to do this.

Comment: Do you want `.str.match('hello|world')`?

Comment: updated the working and output of ```find``` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re
df.text.apply(lambda x:[m.start() for m in re.finditer('hello|world',x,flags=re.I)])
```

---

```
0    [0, 6]
1    [0, 6]
2        []
```